# testing a function in jest javascript

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I have the following onClick function

```
onClickFunction= index => () => {
  this.setState({ activeIndex: index });
}
```

Which is used in the following function

```
getPersons= (persons) => persons
  .map((person, index) => (
     <StyledComponentHeader
        key...
        ...
        onClick={this.onClickFunction(index)}
      >
        <Styled2
          ...
        >
          {person.name}
        </Styled2>
      </StyledComponentHeader>
    ))
```

in my unit test I need to test the `onClickFunction`. currently I have something like this

```
const component= (
  <StyledComponent
    persons={persons}
  />);

describe('...', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(component);
});

it('testing name', () => {
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  expect(wrapper.state().activeIndex).toEqual(0);
  wrapper.instance().onClickFunction(1);
  expect(wrapper.state().activeIndex).toEqual(1);
});
```

it returns saying that the above last `except` should be 0. What is the correct way to test this function?

Comment: Since `onClickFunction` does not change the state, but returns a function which if is called then changes the state, the logical way would be to test it with `wrapper.instance().onClickFunction(1)()` (*notice the added `()` at the end to invoke the returned function*)

Comment: Works like a charm, wasn’t a million miles off! Thanks! If you put it as an answer I’ll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onClickFunction` does not change the state, but returns a function which if called then changes the state, the logical way would be to test it with

```
wrapper.instance().onClickFunction(1)();
```

(*notice the added `()` at the end to invoke the returned function*)